# vertical multilevel menu, Next level should be shown on Hover

Tags: jquery, html, css

This image is showing vertical menu but it is expanded i want only parent tag first, on hover next level should be shown and so on

```
function display_children($parent, $level, $categoryModel) {

    $result = $categoryModel->get_category($parent);
    echo "<ul>";
    foreach ($result as $row) :
        if ($row['Count'] > 0) {
            echo "<li><a href='" . base_url() . "/index.php/advertisement/category/" . $row['category_id'] . "'>" . $row['category_name'] . "</a>";
            display_children($row['category_id'], $level + 1, $categoryModel);
            echo "</li>";
        } elseif ($row['Count'] == 0) {
            echo "<li><a href='" . base_url() . "/index.php/advertisement/category/" . $row['category_id'] . "'>" . $row['category_name'] . "</a></li>";
        } 
            else;
    endforeach;
    echo "</ul>";
}
```

This is my code for which i need css. It is recursive logic that is why i am confused. I found many css but it has horizontal menu listing. I need vertical menu listing.

[image: multilevel menu]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, I've made up a random list. The trick here is to use CSS cascades to our advantage. I've made so every UL inside another UL hidden by nature. Then I make every UL that are exact children of hovered LI show themselves.

```css
ul{
/*If bullets are outside, hover effect will flicker.*/
list-style-position:inside;
}

ul ul{
display:none;
}

li:hover>ul{
display:block;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    A
    <ul>
      <li>B</li>
      <li>C</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
  D
    <ul>
      <li>
      E
        <ul>
          <li>F</li>
          <li>
          G
            <ul>
              <li>H</li>
              <li>I</li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>
      J
        <ul>
          <li>K</li>
          <li>L</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```